# Session in java servlet

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, jakarta-ee

I would like to do the servlet program for the below,"create a servlet named com.SessServlet.If you are accessing the servlet in a new browser then 
for the first time it should display ‘Welcome, Newcomer’. When you refresh the same page it should display‘Welcome Back. You are visiting the page for `<no of times you have refreshed the page>`’."

```
`package com.SessServlet122;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class SessServlet extends HttpServlet
{

public void service(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException
{
    res.setContentType("text/html");
    int i;
    PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
    HttpSession hs=req.getSession();
    i=0;
    if(hs.isNew())
    {

        pw.println("Hello:::"+i);
    }
    else
    {    i++;
        pw.println("Welcome Back:Ur entry count is::::"+i);
    }

    pw.close();
}
}`
```

But this code is not working properly. How to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason is, i is created every time a request hits the server and your service method get called. You have to store i somewhere else. If you want an i per user, the session is the place to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store that counter as a `sessionVariable`, that way you will get it work.
You need this line after your `pw.close();` call:

```
hs.setAttribute("counter", i);
```

Also, the initialization of your counter `i` should look like this:

```
Integer i = (Integer)hs.getAttribute("counter");
if (i == null)
    i = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- Create a [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- From [`service()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#service%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) method retrieve session and [set an attribute](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api//javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) in session if its there else set ans display appropriate message
- On jsp use JSTL to display the counter, for example :  if the attribute set was hitCount then on jsp use `${hitCount}`